# Exclusão em chave estrangeira

Tags: java, jsf

Ajuda na lógica. 
Minha duvida é a seguinte:

Tenho um relacionamento simples entre Lancamento e Pessoa, onde pessoa_id é a chave estrangeira em Lancamento

Classe Modelo

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "pessoa_id")
public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
}
```

Quando vou excluir os Lançamentos tudo funciona corretamente, porem quando vou excluir Pessoa o sistema nao aceita mesmo quando nao existem
dados na tabela de Lancamento, tentei fazer uma logica para tal e sem sucesso.
O correto seria a mensagem de que não é possivel excluir uma Pessoa pois está vinculada ao Lancamento, mas caso nao exista Lancamento, eu
teria que excluir Pessoa, e isso não acontece.

Classe Service

```
@Transactional
public void excluir(Pessoa pessoa) throws NegocioException {
    pessoa = this.pessoas.porId(pessoa.getId());

    if (lancamento.getPessoa().getNome().contains(pessoa.getNome())) {
        throw new NegocioException("Pessoa vinculada a um Lançamento.");
    } else {
        this.pessoas.remover(pessoa);
    }
}
```

Classe Repository

```
public class Pessoas implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private EntityManager manager;

@Inject
public Pessoas(EntityManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}

public void remover(Pessoa pessoa) {
    this.manager.remove(pessoa);
}

public Pessoa porId(Long id) {
    return manager.find(Pessoa.class, id);
}
```

}

XHTML

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" process="@this" 
   update="@form"
   action="#{consultaPessoasBean.excluir}">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{pessoa}" 
        target="#{consultaPessoasBean.pessoaSelecionada}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Na classe repository, inclui o flush, como abaixo:

```
public void remover(Pessoa pessoa) {
    this.manager.remove(pessoa);
    this.manager.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)   
@JoinColumn(name = "pessoa_id")
public Pessoa getPessoa() {
    return pessoa;
}
```

Comment: Qual  erro que é mostrado com você tenta excluir?

Comment: Esta solução não funcionou.    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`financeiro`.`lancamento`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ax5wcm3fcn1xss5lkmlbt68pu` FOREIGN KEY (`pessoa_id`) REFERENCES `pessoa` (`id`))

Comment: Muda o relacionamento de pessoa para lancamento.

Comment: Não amigo, não é esta a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Ao criar a tabela você precisa adicionar a opções ON DELETE CASCADE.

E no seu método remove você precisa validar se existe algum registro relacionado, caso contrário executa o metodo.

Segue referencia.

https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/como-deletar-registros-utilizando-o-cascade/30575